# Dynamically build __all__ for auto-completion

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to dynamically build out `__all__` in a `__init__.py` that will bring classes from many files into one namespace AND be given as suggestions in my editor. I've got the first part working. What I can't get working, though, is the ability to have my editor auto-complete discover everything that's in `__all__` (I also tried updating `__dir__` and defining a `dir()`/`__dir__()` method to no success).

For example, my directory tree is this:

```sh
things/
    __init__.py
    one.py
    two.py
```

In `__init__.py`, I have code that automatically discovers classes `One` and `Two` (that are in their so-named files). However, in VS Code, when I type `from things import` , none of the suggestions are `One` or `Two` in the same way as when I type `from things.one import` , and have `One` suggested to me. If I manually type it all out, everything works fine, but I would really like to have the auto-complete working.

If I define `__all__` with static names, VS Code auto-complete works as expected.

I've been scouring the Internet on this question to no avail and wonder if anyone has any tips or thoughts on how to accomplish it.

Here is what I have in `__init__.py`:

```py
"""Import all submodules so they are available from the top level"""
import pkgutil
import sys
from importlib import import_module
from pathlib import Path

__all__ = []


def _class_name(module_name):
    """Assume camelCase class name form snake-case filename."""
    return "".join([x.title() for x in module_name.split("_")])


# Loop through all modules in this directory and add to namespace
for (_, mod_name, _) in pkgutil.iter_modules([Path(__file__).parent]):
    # Ensure that module isn't already loaded
    if mod_name not in sys.modules:
        loaded_mod = import_module("." + mod_name, package=__name__)

        # Load class from imported module
        name = _class_name(mod_name)
        loaded_class = getattr(loaded_mod, name, None)
        if not loaded_class:
            continue

        # Add this class to the top-level namespace
        setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, loaded_class)
        __all__.append(getattr(loaded_mod, name))
```

Comment: Perhaps VSCode reads the source code, rather than executing it and using the resulting context?

Comment: I restored what you said. I coule get a prompt by using “Ctrl + space”. Could you show your __init__.py？

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I updated my question to include my `__init__.py`. While I get a prompt for autocomplete, I do not get the dynamically imported classes that I want to see.

I believe you might be right, @snakecharmerb, and VS Code doesn't fully execute the code, but rather just extends `__all__` or calls `__dir__()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my directory:

[image]

This is my **init**.py:

[image]

When I use shortcut `ctrl+space`, I can get the following tips(hi is belong to a.py while hello is belong to b.py):

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works wonderfully. I tried to make that point in my original post, and I apologize if it wasn't clear. Hardcoding the imports works great for auto-completion. And dynamically adding the imports works great for easy extensibility. However, I can't find a way to have it both ways: dynamically including all classes and also having auto-complete work.